# How to run a function N trials Python

Tags: python

I have a function that determines if two people have the same birthday

```
ClassSize=40
Birthdays=numpy.random.randint(366, size=ClassSize)
def SameBday(Birthdays):
    if len(Birthdays) != len(set(Birthdays)):
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

I would like to run this function a certain number of trials and see how many times it gives true and how many times it gives false. How should I go about this?

Comment: Hint: Don't use names with capital first letters for anything that is not a class. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to do the same thing over and over in Python `for` a certain number of times...or maybe `while` a certain condition was `True`. Bah, that's just a pipe dream!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the result inside your function, return the value.  Then you can call your function multiple times and store the results to a list (either in a for-loop or via list comprehension).

```
def same_birthday(birthday_list):
    """Returns True if there are any shared birthdays in the supplied list"""
    return len(birthday_list) != len(set(birthday_list))

num_trials = 100
class_size = 40
trial_results = []
for i in range(num_trials):
    birthday_list = numpy.random.randint(366, size=class_size)
    trial_results.append(same_birthday(birthday_list))

print(trial_results)
```

Comment: Your indention is broken.

Comment: Ah, missed a close-paren in the same_birthday function.  Fixed it; thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy

def test_same_bday(lst):
        if len(lst) != len(set(lst)):
                return False  # fail to pass
        else:
                return True  # all different, pass the test

class_size=40
birthdays_list = list()
for i in xrange(class_size):
        birthdays = numpy.random.randint(366, size=class_size)
        birthdays_list.append(birthdays)

result = [test_same_bday(birthdays) for birthdays in birthdays_list]

print 'result: ', result
print 'trials: ', len(birthdays_list)
print 'passed: ', sum(result)
```

Output example:

> result:  [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>   trials: 40
>   passed:  4

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop in range of the number of trial, return return `len(birthdays) != len(set(birthdays))` which will be either True or False. You can sum the total times you get two birthdays on the same day and simply subtract  the total number of trials / how many times we had the same birthday from 1 to get the percentage.

```
import numpy

def same_bday(birthdays):
    return len(birthdays) != len(set(birthdays))

class_size = 40
same = 0
trails = 100000

for trial in range(trails):
    birthdays = numpy.random.randint(366, size=class_size)
    same += same_bday(birthdays)

print("Total percentage of same birthdays {}",format(1.0 - same / trails))
```